# How to disable DrawerLayout Shadow

Tags: android-layout, drawerlayout

I am trying to disable the DrawerLayout shadow and i am not finding the relevant answer. can anyone please assist

thanks in advance

i have also tried setDrawerLayout(null,Gravity.Left) but it still does not work

Comment: Please assist me as i have researched and could not find the answer

Comment: is there any xml solution?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I'm Assuming that's what you mean. The shadow on the drawers (in between the drawer and the background content) is disabled by default and can be set with the

```
setDrawerShadow(Drawable shadowDrawable, int gravity)
setDrawerShadow(int resId, int gravity)
```

functions.

Answer (score 1):

> To enable):

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START)
```

> To disable:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.END)
```

**NOTE:** 
For those who needs perfect drawer shadow, go to link-below and put shadows to your project directory files respectively:

https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip

Answer (score 1):

To disable the drawer layout shadow, the following line is enough ,

mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);