# How to set drawerlayout below toolbar with coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an xml like this, when I show drawer layout, It overlays `Toolbar`, I want my drawerlayout below my `Toolbar`, I cannot figure out how to do it, I tried lots of stuff and I tried it all day long. How can I use `CoordinatorLayout` with `DrawerLayout` without overlapping the `Toolbar` ?

**This is my actionbar style:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolBarTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_behavior="com.frt.poppcar.utils.FabBehavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main"
                android:textColor="@color/five"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me very well.. u need to have coordinator layout as parent layout and set layout behavior for ur drawer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- to make toolbar scroll and hide towards upside include this line
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"-->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_content"/>-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It works because the coordinator layout is aimed to handle different animation or interactions like the side menu, etc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not recommended to do this because of [Material Design Style Guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#)
So then, you should define `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your toolbar Layout first. after that define `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your NavigationView layout. it's kind of a trick.

Comment: It is a trick, yes, but actionbar is still in drawer shadow, I don't want that, how can I possibly do this ? do you have any more ideas ? thank you much

Comment: @mike [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009662/how-to-disable-drawerlayout-shadow)

Comment: @milad.molafi , I don't want to lose shadow

Comment: @mike drop the shadow by that code->trick with minimumHeight and frameLayout

Answer (score 1):

I think it is too late but you may want to know what was the problem or what you could do.Anyways.

New `Support Design Library` included `NavigationDrawer` which you could use it like this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34921695/4409113

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

And this should work now after adding and editing some mistakes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coorinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolBarTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/root_coorinator"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!--<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="main"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>-->

    <!--Don't use it like that, Use NavigationDrawer instead-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And one thing more, you could use that `Toolbar` alone without adding that `TextView` as a title.

Also, you could use that layout inside the `NestedScrollView`.