# Android NavigationView remove elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigationview

I cannot remove elevation (shadow) of `NavigationView` for Lollipop and higher versions.
I added `mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` to my `DrawerLayout`, but it affects on pre-Lollipop versions. I also tried to add `app:elevation="0dp"` and `android:elevation="0dp"` to my `NavigationView` but unsuccessful.

[image]

I need to get the result of android 4 on android 6.

Comment: " I also tried to add app:elevation="0dp" and android:elevation="0dp" to my NavigationView but unsuccessful." - Thats becouse you have to set app:elevation="0dp" for NavigationDrawer, not NavigationView. Just for people looking for help in future, since thats quite old post :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Heres a solution with just xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
yourDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.someDrawable, GravityCompat.START);
```

[How to disable DrawerLayout Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009662/how-to-disable-drawerlayout-shadow)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, i tried it. No effect for Android 6. my `R.drawable.someDrawable` is `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</shape>`. Also the solution you have linked is from 2013, unfortunately, it doesn't work for > android 5.0. I suppose the problem is elevation. UPD: I just tried to use png image as `R.drawable.someDrawable`. Unfortunately, no effect.

Comment: The ''someDrawable' should be a PNG file like this: https://developer.android.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/res/drawable-hdpi/drawer_shadow.9.html
Try to use GravityCompat.END instead of GravityCompat.START